# Ajuda com uma consulta mysql

Tags: mysql

pessoal to quebrando a cabeça aqui com uma consulta que montei onde pego as datas informadas no formulário e busco no banco de dados.

ele faz a consulta só que não traz todos os dados

Se eu informo a data inicial de 01/01/2017 até a data de hoje 15/11/17 ele somente traz até o dia 13/10/2017.

se informo apenas a data inicial ele traz todas as informações, se informo apenas a data final ele não traz nada, então o meu problema está na data fim <=

como arrumo isso?

o meu select está assim:

```
SELECT c.dia, c.mes, c.ano, c.id id_pedido, c.total total_pedido, c.tipo, d.cat_id id_prod,
SUM( d.valor_total ) total_prod
FROM lc_controle c
INNER JOIN lc_detalhe d ON d.controle_id = c.id
WHERE c.tipo =  '0'  and
        ano >= '$anoIni' AND
        mes >= '$mesIni' AND
        dia >= '$diaIni' AND
        ano <= '$anoFim' AND
        mes <= '$mesFim' AND
        dia <= '$diaFim'
    GROUP BY
        c.id,
        c.total,
        d.cat_id
```

Answer (score 2):

O correto é você usar o BETWEEN:

```
$data_inicial = "2017-01-01";
$data_final = "2018-01-01";

SELECT c.dia, c.mes, c.ano, c.id id_pedido, c.total total_pedido, c.tipo, d.cat_id id_prod,
SUM( d.valor_total ) total_prod
FROM lc_controle c
INNER JOIN lc_detalhe d ON d.controle_id = c.id
WHERE data BETWEEN '".$data_inicial."' AND '".$data_final."'
AND WHERE c.tipo =  '0' 
    GROUP BY
        c.id,
        c.total,
        d.cat_id
```